# Slide div inside another div effect

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create sliding images effect:
Online demo[link text](http://www.webdevout.net/test?09&raw).

The problem is when you click rapidly and randomly on the buttons and not wait for animation to finish causing unpredicted  results and even stopping the functionality to work. (and once it stopped in the middle of 2 images...)

How Can I make it work without bugs?
I know that there are some other tools for that sliding like jquery and other approaches like changing the position attribute and not the scrollLeft attribute.
But I want to do it as it is, with scrollLeft, if it possible of course.

The Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                padding:0px;
                margin:0px;
            }
            #imageContainer
            { 
                width: 500px;
                position: relative;             
            }
            #div
             {              
                overflow: hidden;
                white-space: nowrap;                            
            }

            #div img {
                cursor: pointer;
                vertical-align: bottom;
                width: 500px;
                padding:0px;
                margin:0px;
                display:inline;
            }


        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">                        
            var scrollIntervalID;
            var currentIndex=0;                                

            function Scroll(ind){

                var dir = ind ==currentIndex?0:ind<currentIndex?-1:1;
                var steps = Math.abs(ind-currentIndex);

                scrollIntervalID = setInterval(function(){
                    var i=(steps*10)-1;
                    return function(){
                        if (i <= 0) 
                            clearInterval(scrollIntervalID);
                        var elm = document.getElementById("div");                   
                        elm.scrollLeft +=dir * 50;
                        i--;   

                        document.getElementById("span").innerHTML=elm.scrollLeft;

                    }
                }(), 15);
                currentIndex=ind;
            }            

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="imageContainer">
            <div id="div">
                <img id="image1" src="Images/pic1.jpg" width="500px"/><img id="image2" src="Images/pic2.jpg" width="500px"/><img id="image3" src="Images/pic3.jpg" width="500px"/><img id="image4" src="Images/pic4.jpg" width="500px"/>
            </div>          
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="button" value="1" onclick="Scroll(0);"/>
            <input type="button" value="2" onclick="Scroll(1);"/>
            <input type="button" value="3" onclick="Scroll(2);"/>
            <input type="button" value="4" onclick="Scroll(3);"/>
        </div>
        <span id="span"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sriously recommend you to use frameworks like jQuery but if you insist to work on the current version, you have to take care of scenarios which happens during the animation.

You have `scrollIntervalID`, but it is not used outside the scope of the function. You can try clearing the interval timer by using [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) when a previous sliding animation is in progress and advance the position to the intended one before performing the next animation.

Comment: Your second paragraph was very helpful,  I tested it few times and it seems to work fine. For now I will accept this answer, and if latter there will be still a bug i will reopen this question and we will try some thing else i hope :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the previous animation from operating before starting a new one. At the beginning, set:

```
var scrollIntervalID= null;
```

Then at the start of `function Scroll` add:

```
if (scrollIntervalID!==null) {
    clearInterval(scrollIntervalID);
    scrollIntervalID= null;
}
```

You'll also want to base the starting position of the animation on the current value of `scrollLeft`, rather than trying to remember the `currentIndex`.

Comment: setting scrollIntervalID to null and checking it if it's null doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

this is a quick fix, I am not a javascript expert. but it works based on my quick testing

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
        }
        #imageContainer
        { 
            width: 500px;
            position: relative;             
        }
        #div
         {              
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;                            
        }

        #div img {
            cursor: pointer;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            width: 500px;
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
            display:inline;
        }


    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">                        
        var scrollIntervalID;
        var currentIndex=0;                                
        var start = true;
        function Scroll(ind){
            if(start){
            var dir = ind ==currentIndex?0:ind<currentIndex?-1:1;
            var steps = Math.abs(ind-currentIndex);

            scrollIntervalID = setInterval(function(){
            start = false;
                var i=(steps*10)-1;
                return function(){
                    if (i <= 0) 
                        clearInterval(scrollIntervalID);
                    var elm = document.getElementById("div");                   
                    elm.scrollLeft +=dir * 50;
                    i--;   

                    document.getElementById("span").innerHTML=elm.scrollLeft;

                }
            }(), 0);
            currentIndex=ind;
            start = true;
            }
        }            

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="imageContainer">
        <div id="div">
            <img id="image1" src="Images/pic1.jpg" width="500px"/><img id="image2" src="Images/pic2.jpg" width="500px"/><img id="image3" src="Images/pic3.jpg" width="500px"/><img id="image4" src="Images/pic4.jpg" width="500px"/>
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" value="1" onclick="Scroll(0);"/>
        <input type="button" value="2" onclick="Scroll(1);"/>
        <input type="button" value="3" onclick="Scroll(2);"/>
        <input type="button" value="4" onclick="Scroll(3);"/>
    </div>
    <span id="span"></span>
</body>
```